# Unity3d vector and matrix operations

Tags: unity, matrix

**I have the following three vectors:**

- posA: (1,2,3)
- normal:   (0,1,0)
- offset:   (2,3,1)

I want to get the vector representing the position which is offset in the direction of the normal from posA.

**I know how to do this by cheating (not using matrix operations):**

```
Vector3 result = new Vector3(posA.x + normal.x*offset.x
                             posA.y + normal.y*offset.y,
                             posA.z + normal.z*offset.z);
```

**I know how to do this mathematically**
Note: [] indicates a column vector, {} indicates a row vector

```
result = [1,2,3] + {2,3,1}*{[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]}
```

**What I don't know** is which is better to use and if it's the latter how do I do this in unity? I only know of 4x4 matrices in unity. I don't like the first option because you are instantiating a new vector instead of just modifying the original. Suggestions?

Note: by asking which is better, I am asking for a quantifiable reason, not just a preference.

Comment: I'd say that doing it only with a Vector3 in this case is better, as it will be faster than transforming it by a matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hate answering my own questions, but here is what I did to solve this:

Unity has Vector3.scale. I assumed this was just scalar multiplication, but instead it's component-wise multiplication of vectors which is what I was doing with the matrices. The Vector3 class already has the + operator for component-wise addition, so this got really easy.

```
Vector3 result = posA + Vector3.Scale(normal,offset);
```

Haven't tested it, but it looks right

Though, I'm assuming the scale method is implemented using the exact code from my first example, at least it's cleaner now. I may write a method that uses references to modify the passed parameter so I'm not creating new instances just for this.

Comment: Don't hate your own answers. SE sites are good because others come later and say "hey, he solved my problem, +1"

Comment: You can use Matrix4.TRS if you want to operate directly on the Matrix4. http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.SetTRS.html